# Count weekly (last 7 days) posts from a taxonomy.php page

Tags: wordpress, post, count, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

On my taxonomy archive page, I display terms and child terms of the queried taxonomy.
I also want to echo the number of posts associated with each child term. The code below works fine, BUT I want to count only recent/new posts, eg. posted within the last 7 days.

Is it possible to filter `$term->count` in any way to achieve this?

```
$taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');

// get main terms
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, 
    array( 'orderby'    => 'name' ) 
);

// display terms
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<h2 class="text-center">' . $term->name . '</h2>';

    // display term children as list
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
    $child_terms =  get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy );
    
    echo '<ul class="lesson-categories">';
    foreach ( $child_terms as $child_term ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child_term, $taxonomy );            
        echo '<li>';
        echo $term->name;

        // SHOW POST COUNT
        echo $term->count;

        echo '</li>';       
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a custom function, querying our current [taxonomy term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) and specifying a `date_query` [`after`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters) attribute.

```php
/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/66780352/3645650
 * `get_posts_tally_weekly( $post_type = 'post', $post_status = 'any', $taxonomy = 'category', $term = 'uncategorized' );`
 * @return Integer Return a weekly posts tally.
 * @param String $post_type (Optional) Post type to query. Default to 'post'.
 * @param String $post_status (Optional) Post status to query. Default to 'any'.
 * @param String $taxonomy (Optional) Taxonomy to query. Default to ''.
 * @param String $term (Optional) Term to query. Default to ''.
 */
function get_posts_tally_weekly( $post_type = 'post', $post_status = 'any', $taxonomy = 'category', $term = 'uncategorized' ) {
    $query = new WP_Query( [
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'post_status' => $post_status,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        $taxonomy => $term,
        'date_query' => [
            'after' => '1 week ago'
        ],
    ] );
    return $query->found_posts;
    wp_reset_postdata();
};
```

On the front-end we can call our custom function `get_posts_tally_weekly()`. We can specify the `$post_type`, `$post_status`, `$taxonomy` and `$term`.

From a taxonomy page, to retrieve the weekly posts count:

```
<?= get_posts_tally_weekly( 'custom-post-type-slug', 'publish', get_queried_object()->taxonomy, get_queried_object()->slug ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to 'date_query', that did the trick. I had difficulties implementing your function. So I modified your query and placed it directly into my taxonomy archive.

Comment: Alright, don't hesitate to post your answer to, people might find it relevant!

Answer (score 0):

Answer based @amarinediary solution.
A new WP_Query with `date_query` did the trick:

```
// SHOW POST COUNT
$post_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'guided_lessons',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $child_term,
        ),
    ),
    // Checking for the date here
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '1 week ago',
        ),
    ),
);
$post_query = new WP_Query( $post_args );
$new_posts = $post_query->found_posts;
echo $new_posts;
```